# suitable category with the same content in the database

Tags: php, html, mysqli

This is so that when I get this from the database:

```
<select name="kategori" class="tekst">
<option value="hey">hey</option>
<option value="ac">ac</option>
</select>
```

So that is when "Hey" will turn into Hello world that does not exist in the database then it should come forward and tell it that around that there is an error.

So I'm thinking like this, where to find the `$_POST['kategori']` does not match the same with `$text`, so it must be put in `$error=1` but, like I'm trying to make it do so

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT tekst FROM kontaktkategori')) { 
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($tekst);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            if($_POST["kategori"] != $tekst)
            {
                $error = 1;                 
            }

        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
```

The problem, I would like to figure out a way of `kategori` is the same as `$text`, and if it is not the same as it must specify a `$error = 1`.

EIDT:

```
if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT tekst FROM kontaktkategori WHERE tekst = ?')) { 
        $stmt->bind_param('s', $tekst);
        $tekst = $_POST["kategori"];
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($tekst);
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {

            if($_POST["kategori"] != $tekst)
            {
                $error = 1;                 
            }

        }
        $stmt->close();
    } else {
        echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen: ' . $this->mysqli->error;
    }
```

Comment: why can't you do it in query itself? no need of while loop at all.

Comment: @kumar_v I can not exactly see what you mean completely?

Comment: For ex: `SELECT tekst FROM kontaktkategori where tekst = '".$_POST["kategori"]."'`. This is just example. You can do it as per your method.

Comment: it does not work .. :( @kumar_v

Comment: no need of while. just check number of records from execution result(  $stmt->execute();)

Comment: @kumar_v you mean its her; `if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT tekst FROM kontaktkategori WHERE tekst = ?')) { 
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $tekst);
      $tekst = $_POST["kategori"];
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->close();
  }`

Comment: Actually I dont know what framework you are using. For general case, you can check the condition in query itself. So if it matches, the you will get record. Then you can the record count alone. no need to check the result data wit Post data.

Comment: i cant not see what you mean on its?